# binding three dataframes with rbind

Tags: r

I have three sets of data with the same variables and different observations. The variables all share the same name, but when I try to bind them using the `rbind` function I see this:

> names do not match previous names.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem? My desired goal is to have one dataset with numerous observations of the same variables.

What I have tried so far is this:

#### Daten1

```
> attach(Daten1)

rel.Var.1 <- data.frame(Q35, Q37, Q38, Q42, Q46, Q47, Q50, Q51, Q52, Q55,  Q60, Q61,
                    Q91_1, Q92_1, Q93_1, Q94_1, Q95_1, Q96_1, Q97_1, Q301_1, Q300_1, Q98_1,
                    Q99_1, Q100_1, Q101_1, Q102_1, Q103_1, Q104_1, Q105_1, Q106_1,
                    Q107_1, Q108_1, Q109_1, Q110_1, Q111_1, Q112_1, Q113_1, Q114_1,
                    Q115_1, Q116_1, Q117_1, Q118_1, Q119_1, Q121_1, Q122_1,
                    Q123_1, Q124_1, Q125_1, Q126_1, Q127_1, Q128_1, Q129_1, Q130_1,
                    Q131_1, Q132_1, Q133_1, Q134_1, Q135_1, Q136_1, Q137_1, Q138_1,
                    Q139_1, Q140_1, Q141_1, Q142_1, Q143_1, Q144_1, Q145_1, 
                    Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14, Q15, Q16, Q17, Q18, Q19, Q20,
                    Q21, Q22, Q23, Q24, Q25, Q26, Q27, Q28, Q29, Q30, Q31, Q32, Q33,
                    Q176, Q177, Q178, Q175, VPN)
>detach(Daten1)

>rel.Var.1 <- rel.Var.1 %>% rename( 
neo_01 = Q35, neo_03 = Q37,neo_04 = Q38, neo_08 = Q42, 
neo_12 = Q46,neo_13    = Q47, neo_16 = Q50, neo_17 = Q51, neo_18 = Q52,
neo_21 = Q55, neo_26 = Q60, neo_27 = Q61, TICS_1 = Q91_1, TICS_2 = Q92_1,
TICS_3 = Q93_1, TICS_4 = Q94_1, TICS_5 = Q95_1, TICS_6 = Q96_1,
TICS_7 = Q97_1, TICS_8 = Q301_1, TICS_9 = Q300_1, TICS_10 = Q98_1,
TICS_11  = Q99_1, TICS_12= Q100_1, TICS_13 = Q101_1, TICS_14 = Q102_1,   
TICS_15 = Q103_1,
ICS_16 = Q104_1, TICS_17 = Q105_1, TICS_18 = Q106_1, TICS_19 = Q107_1,
TICS_20 = Q108_1, TICS_21 = Q109_1, TICS_22 = Q110_1, TICS_24 = Q111_1, 
TICS_25 = Q112_1,
TICS_26 = Q113_1, TICS_27 = Q114_1, TICS_28 = Q115_1, TICS_29 = Q116_1,  
TICS_30 = Q117_1, TICS_31 = Q118_1, TICS_32 = Q119_1, TICS_33 = Q121_1,
TICS_34 = Q122_1, TICS_35 = Q123_1, TICS_36 = Q124_1, TICS_37 = Q125_1,
TICS_38 = Q126_1, TICS_39 = Q127_1, TICS_40 = Q128_1, TICS_41 = Q129_1,
TICS_42 = Q130_1,
TICS_43 = Q131_1, TICS_44 = Q132_1, TICS_45 = Q133_1, TICS_46 = Q134_1,
TICS_47 = Q135_1, TICS_48 = Q136_1, TICS_49 = Q137_1,
TICS_50 = Q138_1, TICS_51 = Q139_1, TICS_52 = Q140_1, TICS_53 = Q141_1, 
TICS_54 = Q142_1, TICS_55 = Q143_1, TICS_56 = Q144_1, TICS_57 = Q145_1,
HSPS_1 = Q7, HSPS_2 = Q8, HSPS_3 = Q9, HSPS_4 = Q10, HSPS_5 = Q11, 
HSPS_6 = Q12, HSPS_7 = Q13, HSPS_8 = Q14,
HSPS_9 = Q15, HSPS_10 = Q16, HSPS_11 = Q17, HSPS_12 = Q18, HSPS_13 = Q19,   
HSPS_14 = Q20, HSPS_15 = Q21, HSPS_16 = Q22,
HSPS_17 = Q23, HSPS_18 = Q24, HSPS_19 = Q25, HSPS_20 = Q26, 
HSPS_21 = Q27, HSPS_22 = Q28, HSPS_23 = Q29,
HSPS_24 = Q30, HSPS_25 = Q31, HSPS_26 = Q32, HSPS_27 = Q33, 
sex = Q176, Bildung = Q177, Tat = Q178, age= Q175) 

>rel.Var.1 <- na.omit(rel.Var.1)
```

#### Daten 2

```
> attach(Daten2)

rel.Var.2 <- data.frame(Q182, Q186, Q188, Q196, Q204, Q206, Q212, Q214,   
Q216, Q222, Q232, Q234,
Q221, Q222.1, Q223, Q224.1, Q225, Q226.1, Q227, Q174, Q175, Q228.1, Q229,   
Q230.1,Q231, Q232.1, Q233, Q234.1, Q235, Q236.1, Q237, Q238.1, 
Q239,Q240.1, Q241, Q242, Q243, Q244, Q245, Q246, Q247, Q248, Q249, Q251,  
Q252, Q253, Q254, Q255, Q256, Q257, Q258, Q259, Q260, Q261, Q262, Q263,   
Q264, Q265, Q266, Q267, Q268,
Q269, Q270, Q271, Q272, Q273, Q274, Q275,
Q207, Q209, Q211, Q213, Q215, Q217, Q219, Q221.1, Q223.1, Q225.1,
Q227.1, Q229.1, Q231.1, Q233.1, Q235.1, Q237.1, Q239.1, Q241.1, Q243.1,  
Q245.1, Q247.1, Q249.1, Q251.1, Q253.1, Q255.1, Q257.1, Q259.1,
Q6, Q7,Q8, Q5, VPN)

>detach(Daten2)

>rel.Var.2 <- rel.Var.2 %>% rename(
neo_01 = Q182, neo_03 = Q186, neo_04 = Q188, neo_08 = Q196, neo_12 =  
Q204,
neo_13 = Q206, neo_16 = Q212, neo_17 = Q214, neo_18 = Q216, neo_21 = 
Q222,
neo_26 = Q232, neo_27 = Q234, TICS_1 = Q221, TICS_2 = Q222.1, TICS_3 = 
Q223, 
TICS_4 = Q224.1, TICS_5 = Q225, TICS_6 = Q226.1, TICS_7 = Q227, TICS_8 =   
Q174, 
TICS_9 = Q175, TICS_10 = Q228.1, TICS_11 = Q229, TICS_12 = Q230.1,   
TICS_13 = Q231,
TICS_14 = Q232.1, TICS_15 = Q233, TICS_16 = Q234.1, TICS_17 = Q235,  
TICS_18 = Q236.1,
TICS_19 = Q237, TICS_20 = Q238.1, TICS_21 = Q239, TICS_22 = Q240.1, 
TICS_24 = Q241,
TICS_25 = Q242, TICS_26 = Q243, TICS_27 = Q244, TICS_28 = Q245, TICS_29 =   
Q246,
TICS_30 = Q247, TICS_31 = Q248, TICS_32 = Q249, TICS_33 = Q251, TICS_34 =  
Q252, 
TICS_35 = Q253, ICS_36 = Q254, TICS_37 = Q255, TICS_38 = Q256, TICS_39 =  
Q257,
TICS_40 = Q258, TICS_41 = Q259, TICS_42 = Q260, TICS_43 = Q261, TICS_44 =  
Q262,
TICS_45 = Q263, TICS_46 = Q264, TICS_47 = Q265, TICS_48 = Q266, TICS_49 =  
Q267,
TICS_50 = Q268, TICS_51 = Q269, TICS_52 = Q270, TICS_53 = Q271, TICS_54 =  
Q272,
TICS_55 = Q273, TICS_56 = Q274, TICS_57 = Q275, HSPS_1 = Q207, HSPS_2 =  
Q209, 
HSPS_3 = Q211, HSPS_4 = Q213, HSPS_5 = Q215, HSPS_6 = Q217, HSPS_7 =   
Q219, 
HSPS_8 = Q221.1, HSPS_9 = Q223.1, HSPS_10 = Q225.1, HSPS_11 = Q227.1, 
HSPS_12 = Q229.1,
HSPS_13 = Q231.1, HSPS_14 = Q233.1, HSPS_15 = Q235.1, HSPS_16 = Q237.1,  
HSPS_17 = Q239.1,
HSPS_18 = Q241, HSPS_19 = Q243, HSPS_20 = Q245, HSPS_21 = Q247, HSPS_22 =  
Q249,
HSPS_23 = Q251.1, HSPS_24 = Q253.1, HSPS_25 = Q255.1, HSPS_26 = Q257.1,  
HSPS_27 = Q259.1,
sex = Q6, Bildung = Q7, Tat = Q8, age= Q5)

>rel.Var.2 <- na.omit(rel.Var.2)
```

#### Daten3

```
> attach(Daten3)

rel.Var.3 <- data.frame(neo_03, neo_08, neo_12, neo_16, neo_21, neo_26,   
neo_01, neo_04, neo_13,
neo_17, neo_18, neo_27, TICS_1, TICS_2, TICS_3, TICS_4, TICS_5, TICS_6,  
TICS_7, TICS_8, TICS_9,
TICS_10, TICS_11, TICS_12, TICS_13, TICS_14, TICS_15, ICS_16, TICS_17,   
TICS_18, TICS_19, TICS_20, TICS_21, TICS_22,
TICS_24, TICS_25, TICS_26, TICS_27, TICS_28, TICS_29, TICS_30, TICS_31,  
TICS_32, TICS_33, TICS_34, TICS_35, TICS_36,
TICS_37, TICS_38, TICS_39, TICS_40, TICS_41, TICS_42, TICS_43, TICS_44,  
TICS_45, TICS_46, TICS_47, TICS_48, TICS_49, TICS_50,
TICS_51, TICS_52, TICS_53, TICS_54, TICS_55, TICS_56, TICS_57,
HSPS_1, HSPS_2, HSPS_3, HSPS_4, HSPS_5, HSPS_6, HSPS_7, HSPS_8, HSPS_9,  
HSPS_10, HSPS_11, HSPS_12, HSPS_13,
HSPS_14, HSPS_15, HSPS_16, HSPS_17, HSPS_18, HSPS_19, HSPS_20, HSPS_21,  
HSPS_22, HSPS_23, HSPS_24, HSPS_25, HSPS_26, HSPS_27,
Geschlecht, Bildungsabschluss, derzeitige_Beschaeftigung, Alter, NR)
>detach(Daten3)

>rel.Var.3 <- rel.Var.3 %>% rename(
 sex = Geschlecht, Bildung = Bildungsabschluss, Tat =   
 derzeitige_Beschaeftigung, age= Alter, VPN = NR)
>rel.Var.3 <- na.omit(rel.Var.3) 

>View(rel.Var.1)
>View(rel.Var.2)
>View(rel.Var.3)

 ## Datensaetze zusammenfuegen ##bind data

data_gesamt <- rbind(rel.Var.1, rel.Var.2, rel.Var.3)
data_gesamt <- bind_rows(rel.Var.1, rel.Var.2, rel.Var.3)
```

With bind_rows I get this error:

```
Can't combine `..1$neo_01` <character> and `..3$neo_01` <integer>.
Backtrace:
1. dplyr::bind_rows(rel.Var.1, rel.Var.2, rel.Var.3)
2. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
4. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
5. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
6. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
7. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. To better help you, please follow these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are the column names in your three datasets the same?

Comment: Yes, they all have the same names, they are in the same order and they all stem from the same questionnaires. Only the observations are different (different people). Using bind_row (tidyverse) I get this error:

Comment: Can't combine `..1$neo_01` <character> and `..3$neo_01` <integer>.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::bind_rows(rel.Var.1, rel.Var.2, rel.Var.3)
 2. vctrs::vec_rbind(!!!dots, .names_to = .id)
 4. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
 5. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
 6. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 7. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)

Comment: Your error message ("Can't combine ..1$neo_01 <character> and ..3$neo_01 <integer>") says that the issue is mismatched data types, not column names. You're trying to bind a character and an integer, but they need to be the same type